# Subsetting numeric variable but not factor in R

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, lme4

I would like to calculate Linear mixed-effect models via for loop where there is always hard-coded Y and random effect. The X variables (`var.nam[i]`) are to be loop through. I wrote the code and it is working (as I believe), but I would also like to subset X variable (`var.nam[i]`) depending on the X variable (`var.nam[i]`) type (numeric, factor) where:

when X variable (`var.nam[i]`) is numeric, exclude all observation equal to 0

when X variable (`var.nam[i]`) is factor, do not subset X variable (`var.nam[i]`)

A short sample of my code is here:

```
for(i in 1:length(var.nam)) {
        formula[i] <- paste0("Y", "~", paste0(c(var.nam[i], c("Season"), 
                                                          c("Sex"), 
                                                          c("Age"), 
                                                          c("BMI"),
                                                          c("(1|HID)")), collapse="+"))
        model <- lmer(formula[i], data = subset(data, paste0(c(var.nam[i])) != 0))
# loop continues...
}
```

As it is written now, it will subset all X variables (`var.nam[i]`) regardless of the type. Is there any workaround or different way to subset variable, that would work in this specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if this solution works is a bit hard without data or the complete for loop.
Based on your question you want to conditionally subset, adding a if else statement should make this possible:

```
for(i in 1:length(var.nam)) {
        formula[i] <- paste0("Y", "~", paste0(c(var.nam[i], c("Season"), 
                                                          c("Sex"), 
                                                          c("Age"), 
                                                          c("BMI"),
                                                          c("(1|HID)")), collapse="+"))
        data1 <- if(mode(var.nam[i]) == "numeric") {subset(data, paste0(c(var.nam[i])) !=0)} else {data} 
        model <- lmer(formula[i], data = data1)
# loop continues...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! 
I had to alter your code like this:
 `model <- if(mode(var.nam[i]) == "numeric") {lmer(formula[i], data = subset(data, paste0(c(var.nam[i])) !=0)) } else {model <- lmer(formula[i], data = data)} `
But now it works just as I wanted it to.